What will the pressure of accelerated air be relative to the pressure that accelerated it?
Imagine you have a high pressure reservoir filled with air. This reservoir is $1 \,\text{psi}$ above ambient atmospheric pressure. There is also a valve attached to the reservoir.
Now, open this valve. The air will rush and accelerate out, and due to Bernoulli's principle, this fast air will be low-pressure.
Relative to the atmospheric pressure, what will the pressure of the accelerated air be at its maximum velocity? Will the low-pressure-peak be $1 \,\text{psi}$ below ambient? $0.5 \,\text{psi}$?

(All of this is assuming the air is at room temperature, so $21° \,\text{}$Celsius)

When: right away, or after you wait a short time?

@QuantumMechanic I was thinking more of when the jet of air reaches it lowest pressure, so wherever that is located. I will make an edit to add that, good point.

Ok I see. The opposite extreme, thermodynamic equilibrium, is easy to calculate. You take the total amount of air (sum of particles from both partitions) and total volume (sum of volumes) to find the average pressure ($PV=NkT$), which will be equal throughout once the air attains mechanical equilibrium

@QuantumMechanic, I see, that equation does look a little familiar. (ideal gas equation I think). Anyway, sorry to ask something that you might've already answered, but basically the max pressure-low will be the opposite extreme, assuming the temperature stays the same?

That's more complicated, that's why I didn't write an answer! The air actually doesn't speed up. The molecules in the higher pressure part are already whizzing around more quickly (on average), they just bounce off of each other and the walls more often than the low pressure part. So when the valve is opened, they start to escape, collide with slower-moving air, transfer some energy, and slow down. Your max velocity is probably the net velocity of the gas, which will be some average flow of a bunch of particles in one direction, and that might actually be maximized right at the beginning

@QuantumMechanic Oh okay. So, if you were to do a practical experiment and install an array of pressure sensors along the jet of air releasing from the reservoir, what would they say? Like you said, the lowest pressure might be maximized at the beginning when the molecules first exit the valve. If you were to install a pressure sensor there, would it be possible to measure that? Again, sorry if I'm asking something you just explained; I'm having a hard time understand this exact thing.

I'm not 100% sure, not your fault. I bet it would just sense the high pressure inside the valve (pressure is the air molecules moving quickly and bouncing off the wall - when the wall disappears because the valve is opened, the air molecules are still moving just as quickly, so the pressure sensor measures the same pressure that the wall used to feel, ie the 1 psi above atmospheric pressure)

If the container has a small hole, air is initially expelled. But due to inertia, low pressure will eventually be generated inside the container, so air will flow back into the container. Repeat this oscillation until the internal and external pressures are balanced.
